# useAsyncData vs. useLazyAsyncData in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

To my understanding the difference should be that the non-lazy variant blocks the navigation to the page until the promise resolved.

My sample page is pretty simple:

```html
<!-- slow.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    data: {{ data }} <br />
    pending: {{ pending }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data, pending } = useAsyncData(async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
  return 42
})
</script>
```

However, what I experience in reality:

- If I enter the URL and directly load the site (`http://localhost:3000/slow`), it get's server side rendered and loads only after 2s waiting and shows `data: 42` and `pending: false`. Great.
- If I navigate to this page from another one (`<NuxtLink to="/slow">...</NuxtLink>`), so if it gets rendered on client side, nothing is blocked. I immediately see no data and `pending: true`. After 2s it shows `pending: false` and the data. That's not what I would expect.

If I switch to `useLazyAsyncData` the behaviour is exactly the same. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding the proper usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake: You have to use `await useAsyncData` for it to work properly.

Comment: you should not use `await` when using these `useLazyAsyncData`:

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-async-data#uselazyasyncdata

Comment: Never said you should do that. But you should use `await` when using `useAsyncData`.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess.. but i think why you already see something when navigating from another page is because the "app shell" is already loaded and the app does not have to wait until the shell and some other data is computed and ready to be sent to the client

Comment: Probably best as a comment.

Comment: But what's the purpose of `useAsyncData` than at all (in contrast to `useLazyAsyncData`)? Also in nuxt2 the behaviour of `useAsync` was different, i.e. navigation was blocked until data is loaded.

Comment: as Nuxt3 is still in RC i guess that it is a bug